# Почему не работает сортировка через .reverse?

Tags: сортировка, ruby

```
     def alphabetize(arr, rev=true)
books = ["Heart of Darkness", "Code Complete", "The Lorax", "The Prophet", "Absalom, Absalom!"]
    if rev
    books.sort
    else
    books.reverse
    end
end



puts "A-Z: #{alphabetize(books)}"
puts "Z-A: #{alphabetize(books,false)}"
```

После выполнения этого фрагмента выводится:

> A-Z: ["Absalom, Absalom!", "Code Complete", "Heart of Darkness", "The Lorax", "The Prophet"]
>   Z-A: ["Absalom, Absalom!", "The Prophet", "The Lorax", "Code Complete", "Heart of Darkness"]

Почему "Absalom, Absalom!" выходит на первом месте при сортировке "Z-A"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что, `books.reverse` не сортирует, а просто разворачивает массив.

Comment: а замена `books.reverse` на `books.sort.reverse` не будет работать?

Comment: Ты что, как можно! Это же двойной проход по массиву, потеря производительности!

Comment: где двойной проход? насколько я помню, reverse просто возвращает итератор "с конца".